# JayData / Phonegap works in iPad Simulator but not iPad device

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, jaydata

I am doing a proof of concept app using the the following blog as code base.

http://jaydata.org/blog/how-to-check-if-your-websql-environment-is-working

When I run the following in iPad 6.1 Simulator using XCode 4.6.1, I can see the expected output.

```
[LOG] Received Event: deviceready
[LOG] begin testing
[LOG] define Department Entity
[LOG] define Employee Entity
[LOG] saving Entity done.
```

But when I run the following to an actual iPad device via USB, its output ends at "define Department Entity". I don't see any errors; here are the console.log outputs:

```
[LOG] Received Event: deviceready
[LOG] begin testing
[LOG] define Department Entity
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<title>Hello World</title>

<!--jQuery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>

<!--jayData and the different providers used-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/JayData-1.2.7.1/JayData.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/JayData-1.2.7.1/jaydataproviders/SqLiteProvider.js"></script>

<!--PhoneGap-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="app">
    <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
    <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
        <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
        <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jqmReady = $.Deferred(),
        pgReady = $.Deferred();

    // mobileinit does not work. pageinit works.
    // jqm ready
    $(document).bind("pageinit", jqmReady.resolve);

    // phonegap ready
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", pgReady.resolve, false);

    // all ready :)
    $.when(jqmReady, pgReady).then(function () {
        console.log('begin testing');

console.log('define Department Entity');
$data.Entity.extend("$org.types.Department",
{
    Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
    Name: { type: "string", required: true },
    Employees: {
        type: Array,
        elementType: "$org.types.Employee",
        inverseProperty: "Department"
    }
});
console.log('define Employee Entity');
$data.Entity.extend("$org.types.Employee",
{
    Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
    Name: { type: "string", required: true },
    Department: { type: $org.types.Department, inverseProperty: 'Employees' }
});

$data.EntityContext.extend("$org.types.OrgContext", {
    Department: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: $org.types.Department },
    Employee: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: $org.types.Employee }
});

$org.context = new $org.types.OrgContext({
    name: "webSql", databaseName: "OrgDatabase",
    dbCreation: $data.storageProviders.DbCreationType.DropTableIfChanged
});

var department = new $org.types.Department({ Name: 'Department1' });
var employee = new $org.types.Employee({ Name: 'John Smith' });
department.Employees = [employee];

$org.context.onReady(function () {
    $org.context.Department.add(department);
    $org.context.saveChanges();
});

console.log('saving Entity done.');

    });
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you use phonegap, why do you need jaydata? Phonegap has its own [database](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html).

Answer (score 2):

answered on jaydata forum, but I copy here, maybe somebody else will search for this

important points:
1. use jquery 1.8+, 1.7 is not supported. if you must use 1.7 then please use q promise, tell us if you have any problems
2. unfortunatelly you can subscribe to deviceready event after onload event only....

this code works for us on ipad 6.1

```
(function main() {
var jqmReady = $.Deferred();
var pgReady = $.Deferred();

// mobileinit does not work. pageinit works.
// jqm ready
$(document).bind("pageinit", jqmReady.resolve);

// phonegap ready
$.when($.ready)
.then(function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", pgReady.resolve, false);
});

var Employee = $data.define('Employee', {
   Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
   Name: { type: "string", required: true },
   Department: { type: "Department", inverseProperty: 'Employees' }
});

var Department = $data.define('Department', {
   Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
   Name: { type: "string", required: true },
   Employees: { type: Array, elementType: "Employee", inverseProperty: 'Department' }
});

var OrgDatabase = $data.EntityContext.extend('OrgDatabase', {
   Departments: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: Department },
   Employees: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: Employee }
});

var context = new OrgDatabase({name: 'webSql', databaseName: 'OrgDatabase', dbCreation: $data.storageProviders.DbCreationType.DropTableIfChanged});            

// all ready :)
$.when(jqmReady, pgReady, context.onReady()).then(function () {

   var employee = new Employee({ Name: 'John Smith' });
   var department = new Department({ Name: 'Department1' });
   department.Employees = [employee];

   context.Departments.add(department);
   context.saveChanges(function() {
      alert('saving Entity done.');
    });
});
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Web Inspector and found out the app on iPad could not load "JayData.js".

It turns out the actual js file has a filename with all lowercase characters.  Thus, the fix is to change "JayData.js" to "jaydata.js", and the app works on iPad.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html